# request-promise download pdf file

Tags: node.js, request, request-promise

I received multiple pdf files and must download it from a REST-API.

After auth and connect I try to download the file with request-promise:

```
const optionsStart = {
  uri: url,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
      'X-TOKEN': authToken,
      'Content-type': 'applcation/pdf'
    }
  }
  request(optionsStart)
    .then(function(body, data) {
      let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(uuid+'_obj.pdf');
      console.log(body)
      writeStream.write(body, 'binary');
      writeStream.on('finish', () => {
        console.log('wrote all data to file');
      });
      writeStream.end();
    })
```

The request create a pdf (approximately 1-2MB) but I can't open it. (Mac Preview show blank pages and adobe show = >

> There was an error opening this document. There was a problem reading
>   this document (14).

I have no information about the API Endpoint where I download the files. Just have this curl:

```
curl -o doc.pdf --header "X-TOKEN: XXXXXX" 
http://XXX.XXX/XXX/docs/doc1
```

Where is my mistake?

Update:

I opened the file in edit and the file looks like that:
[image: file preview]

Don't have any experience with that :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add encoding: 'binary' to your request options:

```js
const optionsStart = {
  uri: url,
  method: "GET",
  encoding: "binary", // it also works with encoding: null
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/pdf"
  }
};
```

Comment: If `encoding: "binary"` doesn't work try `encoding: null`!

Comment: @boramalper I had excel sheet (.xlsx), null worked perfectly, thank you a lot!

Comment: @BoraM.Alper null works perfect with encryption keys on .dat format

Comment: could this answer be fixed to use null, and there is a typo application/pdf

Comment: I had to use null instead of "binary" as well. Under which circumstances would "binary" work anyway? Is there any documentation?

Answer (score 18):

Add `encoding: null` to your request options:

```
const optionsStart = {
  uri: url,
  method: "GET",
  encoding: null,
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/pdf"
  }
};
```

Then, turn the response into a Buffer (if necessary):

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(response);
```

Comment: If you set `encoding: null` then you do not need to do `Buffer.from(response)` since the response will already be a buffer

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
const optionsStart = {
      uri: url,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          'X-TOKEN': authToken,
          'Content-type': 'application/pdf'
      },
      encoding: null
  }
  request(optionsStart, (err, resp) => {
      let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(uuid + '_obj.pdf');
      writeStream.write(resp.body, 'binary');
      writeStream.on('finish', () => {
        console.log('wrote all data to file');
      });
      writeStream.end();
  })
```